# Actualización de mysql a mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, excel

soy estudiante de primer año en informática y estoy haciendo mi primera aplicación web la cual va dirigida a una organización comunitaria. El siguiente código lo utilizo en mi aplicación para exportar información desde la base de datos a un archivo excel, encontré un código para ello y lo adapté a mi proyecto. El problema es que el código original fué echo para correr con php 5 y yo necesito que corra en php 7. Cambié las sentencias mysql a mysqli pero me de igual forma me da el siguiente error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\consejo_comunal\pages\report\export.php on line 31
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\consejo_comunal\pages\report\export.php on line 31 Sql
> error

Agredezco a quién me puede guiar o indicar que debo corregir.

```
<?php
include "connection.php";

if(isset($_POST['export'])){

    $SQL1 = "SELECT ci as Cedula, CONCAT(lname, ', ', fname, ' ', mname) as Nombre,
        gender as Genero, formerAddress as Direccion, bdate as Fecha_nacimiento, 
        bplace as Lugar_nacimiento, sector as Sector, totalhousehold as Carga_familiar,
        differentlyabledperson as Contacto, relationtohead as Parentesco,
        maritalstatus as Situacion_conyugal, bloodtype as Tipo_sangre,
        civilstatus as Estado_civil, occupation as Ocupacion, ingresomes as Ingresos,
        householdnum as Vivienda, lengthofstay as Tiempo, discapacidad as Discapacidad,
        nationality as Nacionalidad, igpitID as Carnet_patria, gradoinstrucc as Instruccion,
        houseOwnershipStatus as Propiedad_vivienda, waterUsage as Servicio_agua,
        lightningFacilities as Servicio_electrico, sanitaryToilet as Sanitario,
        elector as CNE FROM tblresident group by ci";

    $SQL2 = "SELECT count(*) as Residentes,Sector FROM tblresident group by sector";
    $SQL3 = "SELECT COUNT( * ) as Residentes, Edad FROM tblresident GROUP BY edad";
    $SQL4 = "SELECT count(*) as Residentes,gradoinstrucc as Instruccion from tblresident group by gradoinstrucc";
    $SQL5 = ("SELECT count(*) as Residentes,Elector from tblresident where elector = 'Si' ");
    $SQL6 = ("SELECT count(*) as Residentes,Discapacidad from tblresident where discapacidad != 'Ninguna' ");
    $SQL7 = "SELECT count(*) as Residentes,gender as Genero from tblresident group by gender";

    $arrsql = array($SQL1,$SQL2,$SQL3,$SQL4,$SQL5, $SQL6,$SQL7);
    $arrhead = array("Informacion Residentes Global","Habitantes por Sector","Edades","Grado Instruccion", "Electores", "Discapacitados", "Genero");
    foreach(array_combine($arrsql,$arrhead) as $value => $headers)  {  

    $header = "$headers\n";
    $result ='';
    $exportData = mysqli_query ($value) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysqli_error( ) );
    
    $fields = mysqli_num_fields ( $exportData );
    
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
    {
        $header .= mysqli_field_name( $exportData , $i ) . "\t";
    }
    
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row( $exportData ) )
    {
        $line = '';
        foreach( $row as $value )
        {                                            
            if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
            {
                $value = "\t";
            }
            else
            {
                $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
            }
            $line .= $value;
        }
        $result .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
    }
    $result = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $result );
    
    if ( $result == "" )
    {
        $result = "\nNo hay información!\n";                        
    }
    
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset-iso-8859-1");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    print "$header\n$result\n\n";

    }
}  
                            
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es muy recomendable que consultes el [manual en php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) cuando tengas alguna duda. En él encontrarás ejemplos de código con la forma correcta de utilizar las diferentes funciones o métodos.

El error que recibes te está indicando que te falta un parámetro, concretamente el objeto de la conexión que te devuelve `mysqli_connect()` o la instancia de clase con `$conn = new mysqli(...);` ya sea en estilo procedimental (el que parece que usas) o el orientado a objetos, respectivamente.

El orden de los parámetros, también lo puedes consultar en el manual: `mysqli_query($conn,$query);`

Espero que la respuesta de haya resultado útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Si había leído el manual solo que no había entendido, aplique la modificación que indicaste y me dió otro error en la sentencia mysql_field_name e igualmente la corregí con ayuda de esta página, muchas gracias